# Sending GA E-Commerce Events without Pageview

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm working on an implementation of Advanced E-Commerce in a "messy" GA/GTM environment with multiple tags and multiple GTM installs.

In order to manage the complexity and prevent multiple page-views from firing for every page, I'm trying to use events to get the data to send to GA, rather than relying on a page-view for that.

For example,

```
for(var i = 0; i < {{variable}}.length; i++) {
    var product = {{wizely.variable}}[i];
    ga({{TRACKERID}}+'.ec:addImpression', {
        'name': product.name,
        'id': product.ID
        'list': 'LIST',
        'position': i
    })
  }
ga({{TRACKERID}}+".send","event","Ecommerce","Impressions","LIST",{nonInteraction: true});
```

This is working great, but I can't seem to find a list of Ecommerce events that GA will accept, and I'm trying to use this method for things other than impressions.

Example, will this work?

```
ga({{TRACKERID}}+".send","event","Ecommerce","Detail","Detail-Page",{nonInteraction: true});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ga() method you're using is just regular event tracking, you can name them however. The reason you'd use those is to "send" a hit to GA with the ecommerce data.

There are ecommerce actions that you should consider and THEN send the GA event. See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-activities